# Lack of Role and Responsibility Definition and Overlap With Other Groups

Tags: management, manager

I work at a very large company. Recently we went through an Agile transformation however parts were left out in this transformation. In that, some groups came along begrudgingly.

I have been meeting with my boss for about three months and talking with him off and on to ask for what my roles and responsibilities should be. In the mean time, I have been trying to fill in where I think I best fit and trying to lead my team with a fuzzy definition.

I have met with him and proposed a list of roles and responsibilities for my group which he was receptive. However nothing has changed in two months. Additionally, there are other groups who start to encroach on my teams perceived roles and responsibilities. I feel like I have to be on the defensive constantly

In talking with others they also have the same concern and issue. I am not alone

I would look for another job however I am highly paid for my area so it makes it very difficult to find a job in the same pay range.

How do I get my boss to manage ?

Comment: By agile transformation, do you mean Scrum?

Comment: Scaled Agile and DevOps

Comment: You told him your proposed roles and responsibilities and he agreed- why are YOU not leading your team to do them now?  What specifically do you need someone else to do for you?

Answer (score 1):

Even in Agile the role of manager still exists but the details may have changed. I don't know how "Agile" your organisation truly is, but as a manager you need to define the direction the team must take and protect or enable your team. From what you wrote it seems you're trying to do this, at least the protection part.

The main point to address IMO is the following one:

> I have met with him and proposed a list of roles and responsibilities for my group which he was receptive. However nothing has changed in two months.

One way to unlock the situation is to define yourself the responsibilities of your team and not to ask for confirmation but assume confirmation and ask for corrections:

> Hello Boss
> Following the discussion about team X responsibilities I've come up with the following list of responsibilities : (A, B, C)
> I'll forward this list to other team leaders later this week. If you think I missed something or if an item is not the responsibility of the team please let me know.

Advantages are:

- You're showing your boss you're taking care of the issue and presenting a solution
- No answer from your boss is a tacit acknowledgement of your solution
- If you're wrong your boss is forced to take action and help you.